# stripe checkout data-amount dynamic

Tags: jquery, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe checkout for payments. However I am unable to load the dynamic amount from jquery. The data is loading but the amount was not showing the in the checkout window.

This is my form:

```
<form id="paymentform" class="paymentform" action="" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" class="eventkey" id="event" value="#rc.hunt.id#">
          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
                  class="stripe-button" 
                  data-key="pk_test_XKVFQRnWDjkNwPxn3xIomQK6" 
                  data-amount="" 
                  data-email = "#GetAuthUser()#"                       
                  data-name="#rc.hunt.name#" 
                  data-description="Registration Fee $#rc.hunt.registration_fee#" 
                  data-image="/favicon.png" 
                  data-label = "Complete Registration" 
                  data-allow-remember-me = "false" 
                  data-locale="auto" data-zip-code="true">
          </script>
        </form>
```

And Jquery:

```
$(".stripe-button").attr("data-amount", 20000);
```

But this doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set a dynamic amount for Checkout when using the standard integration(that uses the script tag). Instead, you need to use the [custom integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), and then when you open the Checkout popup you can set the `amount` property explicitly:

```
var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
// Open Checkout with further options
handler.open({
  name: 'Demo Site',
  description: 'Custom amount ($' + displayAmount + ')',
  amount: amountInCents,
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/